# how can I pass tap to next responder in Cocoa-Touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have two `UIImageView`: `image1` and `image2`. `image1` overlaps `image2`.
I also have a `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapImage1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouch:)];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapImage2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouch:)];

[tapImage1 setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[self.image1 addGestureRecognizer:tapImage1];

[tapImage2 setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[self.image2 addGestureRecognizer:tapImage2];
```

After tapping on `image1`, in `handleTouch` I want to check some criteria and pass the tap event to the underlying `image2`.

In the future there will be more images, not only 2.

Edit: Further explanation copied from an answer:

I have triangle in `image1`. In `handleTouch` I want to check if tap is inside triangle. If tap is outside triangle then I want to check underlying `image2` which also has triangle. if tap is inside the triangle of `image2` then bring `image2` to front, if not continue to other underlying images if any.

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE, you do not pass anything in there.

Answer (score 0):

Simulating user interaction is generally not a good idea, for many reasons. It's better to focus on what you want to achieve. Do you want image2 to be highlighted, selected, perform a little dance, or something else? Then subclass UIImageView and implement a method that does precisely what you want and let handleTouch: call that method.

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to bring to front image2.

Answer (score 0):

You may subclass UIImageView or UIView and override the [hitTest:withEvent:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCAICB)
Please check the example:

```
-(UIView*) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self _checkCriteria]) {
        return _target;
    } else {
        return  [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    }
}
```